# MySQL Isolation Level Read Uncommitted for Log table

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-performance

I want to log Http request and response to my application in a Mysql table.
Is it possible to set isolation level to READ UNCOMMITTED in this Log table only? If yes, how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

What version of MySQL?

`tx_isolation` is settable at the "Session" level via `SET`.

What will the competing queries be?

Changing tx_isolation *may not* provide much performance improvement.  Do you have a specific example of a problem?